# Why error method not allowed arise when sending "DELETE" method from Next Js component? (POST method is working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

this is my first time here, so, i'm following a youtube video from Javascript Mastery for creating a threads clone. I did finish watching the video from start to end, and of course finish building a thread clone (the functionality is limited to what the video showing). And I already improved the app by adding new features (adding a feedback when posting or doing something, showing replies in logged in user account from specific user, adding time information to all threads that have been posted, improving the small detail for like-comment-share-send buttons, etc), now I'm working on a new feature, that is the logged in user can like other user's threads. I'm already close to achieve what I'm expecting, but now I'm stuck in this problem, the problem is when logged in user click the like button, the post request is made to the server and it is a success because the like document has been made in mongo db, but when the user again click the like button, the delete request is gave me an error like 405 method not allowed, can someone please help me?

below's my code:

LikeButton.tsx

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useLike from "@/hooks/useLike";
import Image from "next/image";

interface Props {
  threadId: string;
  userId: string;
}

const LikeButton = ({ threadId, userId }: Props) => {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [likeFunctions, setLikeFunctions] = useState<{
    addLike: () => Promise<void>;
    removeLike: () => Promise<void>;
  } | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setupLikeFunctions() {
      const likeFunctions = await useLike({ threadId, userId });
      setLikeFunctions(likeFunctions);
    }
    setupLikeFunctions();
  }, [threadId, userId]);

  const handleLike = async () => {
    if (isLiked) {
      await likeFunctions?.removeLike();
    } else {
      await likeFunctions?.addLike();
    }
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };

  const heartImageSrc = isLiked
    ? "/assets/heart-filled.svg"
    : "/assets/heart-gray.svg";

  return (
    <Image
      src={heartImageSrc}
      alt="heart"
      width={24}
      height={24}
      className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
      onClick={handleLike}
    />
  );
};

export default LikeButton;
```

useLike.ts

```
const useLike = async ({
  threadId,
  userId,
}: {
  threadId: string;
  userId: string;
}) => {
  const addLike = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/like", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ threadId, userId }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Handle successful like addition
      } else {
        // Handle error
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  const removeLike = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/like", {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ threadId, userId }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Handle successful like removal
      } else {
        // Handle error
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  return { addLike, removeLike };
};

export default useLike;
```

like.ts

```
import { fetchThreadById } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { fetchUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";
import Like from "@/lib/models/like.model";
import { connectToDB } from "@/lib/mongoose";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST" && req.method !== "DELETE") {
    return res.status(405).end();
  }
  try {
    // const user = await currentUser();
    // if (!user) return null;
    // const userInfo = await fetchUser(user.id);
    const { threadId } = req.body;
    if (!threadId || typeof threadId !== "string") {
      throw new Error("Invalid thread ID");
    }

    const thread = await fetchThreadById(threadId);
    if (!thread) {
      throw new Error("Invalid thread ID");
    }

    if (req.method === "POST") {
      const { threadId, userId } = req.body;
      try {
        await connectToDB();
        const newLike = new Like({
          userId,
          threadId,
        });
        await newLike.save();
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Like added successfully" });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding like: ", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
      }
    }

    if (req.method === "DELETE") {
      const { threadId, userId } = req.body;
      try {
        await connectToDB();
        // Find the like document and delete it
        await Like.findOneAndDelete({ userId, threadId });
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Like deleted successfully" });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error deleting like: ", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).end();
  }
}
```

I already tried to check in useLike.ts if the method in response inside removeLike() is not explicitly set to DELETE and checking inside like.ts if there's logic conflict in if (req.method === "POST") or (req.method === "DELETE")

Comment: Can you try printing value you are getting in `req.method` in `like.ts` file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ShubhamWaje, I already fix the problem, so in my next js project structure, I forgot that I already have a "/root/pages/api" folders, my mistake is I create my like.ts inside "/root/app/api" API in "/root/app/api" is for uploadthing and clerk, so I just moved my like.ts inside "/root/pages/api", and it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I already fix this issue. Here is my project structure:

```
/root
    /app
        /(auth)
        /(root)
        /api
        etc...
    /pages
        /api
    /etc...
```

The problem is, I made like.ts inside a wrong directory, when the problem arise, I place my like.ts inside "/root/app/api" but I already have "/root/pages/api", when I make a request to like API, the endpoint would be "/api/like" and that endpoint would target the like.ts file inside "/root/pages/api" not "/root/app/api" folder

Comment: Okay, now the liking thread functionality has been fully implemented!